# When bringing two tables together how can I make only Photos searchable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've brought two tables together from one database which has a search function applied. At the moment 'photos' are being narrowed down when searching but the contents from 'sponsor' is always displayed. Ideally I want everything to be displayed before searching but then on a search 'sponsor' results will never appear. I've tried to put the $search in the first half with 'photos' but that does the above action. What can I add to stop this?

```
SELECT * FROM photos 
WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'
UNION SELECT * FROM sponsor
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: sorry, but we can't possibly know what you're talking about

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Or, better (imho) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What's the reason for the union with `SELECT * FROM sponsor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two different SQL statements depending on whether or not `$search` is present.

```
if ($search) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos
            WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'
            ORDER BY id DESC";
} else {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM photos
            UNION SELECT * FROM sponsor
            ORDER BY id DESC';
}
```